# Pause/resume the current playing song in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, windows-phone-8

I want to write a method in a Windows Phone Application to pause the current playing song and to resume the song if it has paused.
Like a play/pause button.
What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get it done with the help of the songs stored in the media library the n its easy with the help of MedaPlayer

Use this namespace

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
```

To get all the songs in the media library

```
MediaLibrary mLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
SongCollection songs= mLibrary.Songs;
```

To play a specific song

```
MediaPlayer.Play(songs, int index);
```

To Pause the mediaplayer

```
MediaPlayer.Pause();
```

To continue playing the song

```
MediaPlayer.Play(songs);
```

A simple [demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thank you Aman for the reply. I want to do it like a 3rd party application. Like I do not know what song is playing. Just I want to pause what is playing in the music player. Is that possible in this method. (Working like the hardware pause button on headset)

Comment: yes definitely it would, I am doing it in in one of my apps. I have made a custom play list in my app and a music player kind of page wherein I have kept buttons to play, pause, shuffle and repeat etc. They all work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. "MediaPlayer.Pause();" was enough for me